# Can conditional expectation be used to prove the following result?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables. Is it possible to use the law of total expectation to say

$$
\mathbb{E}[X - \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]] 
= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X - \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y] \mid Y]
= 0.
$$

It seems right but I believe I might be committing some crime.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$\mathbb{E}[X-\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]]=\mathbb{E}[X]-\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]]=\mathbb{E}[X]-\mathbb{E}[X]=0$$
by linearity and the law of total expectation.

Of course, since the above is zero, any expectation (conditional or unconditional) of the above is also zero.